# Do I need to use jQuery Mobile or can I just design a non-native App with CSS and HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm designing an App using HTML and CSS with a little jQuery. I've been using jQuery Mobile, but the default CSS is getting in the way. Can I just essentially create a website with the right dimensions and than turn that into an App?   Thanks. :)

Comment: What are you calling an _App_? A native mobile application? A mobile web site?

Comment: A non-native mobile app.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. A mobile application has to be native.

Comment: I guess it's called a web app? Not something that would open up in a phone's browser.  A downloadable app, but one that's written in html, css and jquery.  Does that make sense?

Comment: That sounds like a native mobile application that has a built in browser. Do you plan to use PhoneGap?

Comment: Do not mix jQuerymobile and PhoneGap! The pages transitions are horribles when wrapped in PhoneGap.

Comment: @jrummell - He is referring to a web app, not a native app. There is a HUGE difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery Mobile is for mobile websites. It uses progressive enhancement to give you the best experience possible for [most mobile devices](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/).

Is it necessary? No, you could use another framework or roll your own.

Update based on PhoneGap comments - You can use any html, javascript, and css that you want to make your website. However, you may find that certain frameworks work better with PhoneGap's browser than others.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using jQuery Mobile with PhoneGap and have not had any problems. If you don't like the transitions you can switch them off.

If you don't want the JQM styling affecting your pages you can simply use the structure-only css rather than the entire CSS - http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.css

For things like form elements you can also add `data-role="none"` to prevent JQM from styling it so that you can add your own styles.

But yes, if you really don't like it you don't have to use JQM.

Answer (score 0):

I built an entire iOS app (approved 10/2012 by Apple) from the ground up with jQuery Mobile. There is some added functionality within the app itself though, but will also function as a web app in a user's browser, and as a mobile site when someone on a different device (i.e. Andriod) visits the URL.

The app is basically a `UIWebView` that pulls in the jQuery Mobile site. Hope that answers your question... but if not, I can provide with more details/tips.